# Magento2.4: How to Add MassActions in ACL list?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.2, magento2.4

I want to add Mass Actions from sale order grid to ACL list so i can restrict those actions to specific user roles?
for example a user can access sales_order grid but cannot access to MassActions or MassActions should not be visible to that user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Create additional ACL**

`app/code/Acme/StackExchange/etc/acl.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Magento_Sales::sales">
                    <resource id="Magento_Sales::sales_operation">
                        <resource id="Magento_Sales::sales_order">
                            <resource id="Magento_Sales::actions">
                                <resource id="Magento_Sales::mass_actions" title="Use Mass Actions" translate="title" sortOrder="200"/>
                            </resource>
                        </resource>
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

[image]

**2. Create custom MassAction class**

`app/code/Acme/StackExchange/Ui/Component/Sales/Order/MassAction.php`

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Acme\StackExchange\Ui\Component\Sales\Order;

use Magento\Framework\AuthorizationInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;

class MassAction extends \Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction
{
    protected const ACL_RESOURCE = 'Magento_Sales::mass_actions';

    protected AuthorizationInterface $authorization;

    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        AuthorizationInterface $authorization,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->authorization = $authorization;

        parent::__construct($context, $components, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function prepare(): void
    {
        if (!$this->authorization->isAllowed(self::ACL_RESOURCE)) {
            foreach ($this->getChildComponents() as $actionComponent) {
                $componentConfig = $actionComponent->getConfiguration();
                $componentConfig['actionDisable'] = true;
                $actionComponent->setData('config', $componentConfig);
            }

            $config = $this->getConfiguration();
            $config['componentDisabled'] = true;
            $this->setData('config', $config);
        }

        parent::prepare();
    }
}
```

**3. Update Sales Order Grid with Custom MassAction class**

`app/code/Acme/StackExchange/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <massaction name="listing_massaction" class="Acme\StackExchange\Ui\Component\Sales\Order\MassAction"/>
    </listingToolbar>
</listing>
```

**4. Optional: Create Controller Action Restriction plugin**

`app/code/Acme/StackExchange/Plugin/Sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/MassActionPlugin.php`

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Acme\StackExchange\Plugin\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order;

use Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\AuthorizationInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;

class MassActionPlugin
{
    protected const ACL_RESOURCE = 'Magento_Sales::mass_actions';

    protected AuthorizationInterface $authorization;

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function __construct(AuthorizationInterface $authorization)
    {
        $this->authorization = $authorization;
    }

    public function beforeExecute(ActionInterface $subject)
    {
        if (!$this->authorization->isAllowed(self::ACL_RESOURCE)) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('You don\'t have permission for this operation.'));
        }
    }
}
```

**5. Apply Restriction plugin to required actions**

`app/code/Acme/StackExchange/etc/adminhtml/di.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\MassCancel">
        <plugin name="Acme_StackExchange_Plugin_Sales_Controller_Adminhtml_Order_MassActionPlugin"
                type="Acme\StackExchange\Plugin\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\MassActionPlugin" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\MassHold">
        <plugin name="Acme_StackExchange_Plugin_Sales_Controller_Adminhtml_Order_MassActionPlugin"
                type="Acme\StackExchange\Plugin\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\MassActionPlugin" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\MassUnhold">
        <plugin name="Acme_StackExchange_Plugin_Sales_Controller_Adminhtml_Order_MassActionPlugin"
                type="Acme\StackExchange\Plugin\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\MassActionPlugin" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Pdfinvoices">
        <plugin name="Acme_StackExchange_Plugin_Sales_Controller_Adminhtml_Order_MassActionPlugin"
                type="Acme\StackExchange\Plugin\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\MassActionPlugin" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Pdfshipments">
        <plugin name="Acme_StackExchange_Plugin_Sales_Controller_Adminhtml_Order_MassActionPlugin"
                type="Acme\StackExchange\Plugin\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\MassActionPlugin" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Pdfcreditmemos">
        <plugin name="Acme_StackExchange_Plugin_Sales_Controller_Adminhtml_Order_MassActionPlugin"
                type="Acme\StackExchange\Plugin\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\MassActionPlugin" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Pdfdocs">
        <plugin name="Acme_StackExchange_Plugin_Sales_Controller_Adminhtml_Order_MassActionPlugin"
                type="Acme\StackExchange\Plugin\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\MassActionPlugin" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**Notes:**

- Don't forget to reset cache
- Don't forget to re-save User Role to apply restrictions and re-login restricted admin user